# HTC One M9 Boot Loop

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, boot-loop, htc-one-m9

I have a HTC One M9 Factory unlocked, never rooted, OEM Software, OEM ALL, last night I was using it and it froze.

-I've tried wiping the cache.
-I've tried factory reset.

But it keeps going in the loop. I've tried unlocking the bootloader but all the tutorials i've seen are telling me to enable it in developer options (wich I can't reach).

Any suggestions?